# Having trouble with three.js camera

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm having trouble to figure out how to use three.js camera.

[image: What i'm trying to achieve]

This is basically what i'm tring to achieve. I have a small map, on which players can spawn at its corners (here, they are represented as cubes), on the sketch it's represented by 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I want the camera to be behind them at startup, represented by the "eye" on my sketch, pointing on the center of the cube 1, the orange line represents the line of sight. I also drew the position of the camera as i want it if i'm the 4th player.

But it will come after. During tests, i was facing a behavior i wasn't expecting. Let me explain, this is what i'm currently doing :

```
camera.position.set(player.position.x, player.position.y + 2, player.position.z + 3);
camera.lookAt(player.position);
```

The `player` variable is a THREE.Mesh. The camera should be placed a bit on top of the player, and it works as expected if the player spawns in 1 or 3, but in 2, it's absolutely wrong : when i'm moving it with my mouse, it rotates around it like its rotating on the Y axis, and i can never see my cube... I thought that the fact that i was using the `lookAt()` method on my player allows me to point at it with my camera, but obviously i was wrong.

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without looking at your code, but here is a sample doing what you describe, which also calls lookAt with an object with keys x, y and z...

http://jsfiddle.net/vn4t6o6u/1/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

    // Place camera on x axis

    scene.add(camera);
        camera.position.set(-6,-6,30);
    camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);    
    camera.lookAt({x:0,y:0,z:0});
    setTimeout(function(){
            camera.position.set(14,-6,30);
        camera.lookAt({x:8,y:0,z:0});  
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
            camera.position.set(-6,14,30);
        camera.lookAt({x:0,y:8,z:0});  
    }, 2000)
    setTimeout(function(){
            camera.position.set(14,14,30);
        camera.lookAt({x:8,y:8,z:0});  
    }, 3000)

    geometry1 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    geometry2 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    geometry3 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    geometry4 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);

    material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    material3 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
    material4 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ffff});

    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);    
    mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material3);    
    mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry4, material4);    

    mesh1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    mesh2.position.set(8, 0, 0);
    mesh3.position.set(0, 8, 0);
    mesh4.position.set(8, 8, 0);

        scene.add(mesh1);
    scene.add(mesh2);
    scene.add(mesh3);
    scene.add(mesh4);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {




    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: what is the up vector for camera ?

Comment: `camera.position.set(14,14,30)` <~~ third param, so 30

Comment: i still don't get it. also, i don't think so but is it a problem that my map is on the X and Z axis ?

Comment: oh, and i think you misunderstood what i said when i asked you about the up vector, i'm talking about camera.up !

Comment: i don't know if that could help you, but i'm using this to control my player and the camera https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html